# SPFx webpart not updating with latest spkg uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, installation, bug

My Spfx spkg uploads successfully to the apps catalog. Tenant wide upload is enabled.

When I do '**Add an App**',

This app is not available for installation under 'From your Organisation'

[image]

Although when I try to add the web-part on a page, this web-part is available there:

[image]

Now I again did some changes to the source code. Updated Spkg file with the new version including the changes done. The web-part is available to be added but the latest changes do not reflect in the web-part.

Any suggestion where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Just keep the version number same and upload the app. It should update automatically. Only if you have added a new webpart or extension would you need to change version number.

Comment: @GautamSheth If I will be using the same version number how am I going to differ the different versions for backup in the apps catalog? Also I don't see workbench changes in the web-part deployed in the apps catalog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realized my mistake, I was directly executing the following command:

```
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Then I executed the folowoing set of commands and it worked this time:

```
gulp clean

gulp bundle --ship

gulp package-solution --ship
```

More details [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-and-deploy-the-client-side-web-part-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Great @mohd tahir, Please don't forget to accept your answer as accepted to close this thread :)