# Webpart don´t update

Tags: deployment, solution-deployment, npm, deploy

First of all, English is not my first language, so bear with me.

I have already developed some solutions with web parts and until now I had no problems deploying a new version. To achieve this I follow these steps:

1. Make changes
2. npm version patch | minor | major
3. gulp sync-version (A subroutine that update sharepoint webpart version)
4. gulp clean
5. gulp build
6. gulp bundle --ship
7. gulp package-solution --ship
8. Drag and drop .spppkg in app catalog
9. In SharePoint go to apps and "Obtain last version"

If i update a "patch" its work. But with a "minor" it just doesnt update.

What am i missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache? 

Please see: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9228
And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/update-host-web-components-in-sharepoint
And: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249536/spfx-webpart-not-updating-with-latest-spkg-uploaded

Comment: Hi @Hamlet, Can you check and confirm if web part version is updated correctly? It should be greater than the previously deployed web part version.